# LTC3106 - getting 3.26v instead of 3.3v

Tags: voltage, noise

We designed a power supply for an iOT. The uses SoCl2 battery and solar panel combination. The circuit is functioning and we are getting 3.26v consistently for over 3 days now. LTC3106 is configured for 3.3v configuration.  At VCC pin we are using 0.1uF instead of 0.01uF since datasheet says 0.1uF can be used. Does the value of capacitance make any difference ? Any other factors to consider to account for voltage drop ? Noise could be one possibility.  Any suggestions or recommendations appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What instrument are you using to measure the output of the LTC3106? 0.04V is within the tolerance of a cheap multimeter.

Comment: Multimeter is not a very accurate one definetely. Will try to measure the voltage using CRT and get back tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3.26V is within specification for the device.

Device manufacturers can only guarantee output voltages to be with a couple of percent. 3.26V is within ~1.5%.

Also as others have commented how accurate is your voltmeter?

It could be anywhere between 3.22 and 3.40V at 25°C.

What is the input supply voltage?

[image]

Comment: Backup battery is SOCl2 with a voltage of 3.67v. Solar panel is giving an output of 4.6v. Currently testing in lab conditions using a constant light source of 2000 lumen. I have not seen the output and presence of noise in CRT terminal as yet. I try out seeing the output in CRT at few possible points in the circuit and post the same tonight. The voltmeter is not a very accurate one for sure

Comment: I verified with oscilloscope. I see output voltage in the range of 3.26 - 3.32v I also noticed 3.30v at 50% of the sampling time. As you pointed out output voltage is well within range mentiomed in datasheet. Thanks  for the help!  To smoothen the output am thinking of LC filter using ferrite bead and a capacitor. LC filter is suggested in this case because it’s a switching regulator?